# Scale tikzpicture size with axis

Tags: pgfplots

How can I make the size of the `tikzpicture` be proportional to the `axis` length? For example, if I plot a function on ranges [0,2*Pi] and [0,3*Pi], how can I make the latter one be 1.5 times wider than the former?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.15} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=major]
    \addplot [blue] expression [domain=0:2*pi,samples=300] {sin(deg(x))*sin(2*deg(x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid=major]
    \addplot [red] expression [domain=0:3*pi,samples=300] {sin(deg(x))*sin(2*deg(x))};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "--shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

[image: mwe]

**UPD 1**
My actual problem involves 3D plot and the suggested in the comments solution via `/pgfplots/x={<dimen>}` requires all three `x`, `y`, `z` to be specified, which disturbs how my initial plot looks like:
[image: mwe_3d]

MWE 3D:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=500,outext=.png},border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        % x=0.08mm,
        % y=50mm,
        % z=0.01mm,
        colorbar horizontal,
        colorbar style={
          separate axis lines,
          at={(0.5,1.03)},anchor=south,
          xticklabel pos=upper,
          title style={yshift=5 pt},
          title={ colorbar title 1} 
        },
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel={ x label},
        ylabel={ y label},
        ymin=1,
        extra y ticks={1}, % force 1 to appear among the ticks.
        grid=major,
        xminorgrids=true,
        minor tick num=1,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=16
        ]
        \addplot3 [contour filled={ levels={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16} }]
        table {
150.0000  1.0000  0.0000
200.0000  1.0000  0.0235
250.0000  1.0000  0.3918
300.0000  1.0000  1.5710
350.0000  1.0000  0.1546
400.0000  1.0000  0.3470
450.0000  1.0000  3.3852
500.0000  1.0000  4.2527
550.0000  1.0000  9.2669
600.0000  1.0000  0.0021
650.0000  1.0000  -0.0000
700.0000  1.0000  -0.0000

150.0000  1.5000  -0.0000
200.0000  1.5000  0.2833
250.0000  1.5000  0.0295
300.0000  1.5000  0.1458
350.0000  1.5000  4.2348
400.0000  1.5000  1.9810
450.0000  1.5000  0.9533
500.0000  1.5000  3.5815
550.0000  1.5000  0.0466
600.0000  1.5000  0.0039
650.0000  1.5000  -0.0000
700.0000  1.5000  -0.0000

150.0000  2.0000  0.0000
200.0000  2.0000  0.1007
250.0000  2.0000  0.0020
300.0000  2.0000  0.3198
350.0000  2.0000  1.5419
400.0000  2.0000  9.1226
450.0000  2.0000  9.4154
500.0000  2.0000  2.5719
550.0000  2.0000  -3.1944
600.0000  2.0000  0.0027
650.0000  2.0000  -0.0000
700.0000  2.0000  -0.0000
        };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        colorbar horizontal,
        colorbar style={
          separate axis lines,
          at={(0.5,1.03)},anchor=south,
          xticklabel pos=upper,
          title style={yshift=5 pt},
          title={ colorbar title 2}
        },
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel={ x label},
        ymin=1,
        extra y ticks={1}, % force 1 to appear among the ticks.
        grid=major,
        xminorgrids=true,
        minor tick num=1,
        point meta min=0,
        point meta max=16
        ]
        \addplot3 [contour filled={ levels={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16} }]
        table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}*1.5] {
150.0000  1.0000  0.0015
200.0000  1.0000  0.1417
250.0000  1.0000  2.1454
300.0000  1.0000  1.1078
350.0000  1.0000  0.0932
400.0000  1.0000  12.6059
450.0000  1.0000  11.5850
500.0000  1.0000  0.1040
550.0000  1.0000  -0.0001
600.0000  1.0000  -0.0000
650.0000  1.0000  0.0005
700.0000  1.0000  0.0266

150.0000  1.5000  0.0028
200.0000  1.5000  0.3706
250.0000  1.5000  0.0697
300.0000  1.5000  0.4941
350.0000  1.5000  0.0306
400.0000  1.5000  7.6033
450.0000  1.5000  15.6078
500.0000  1.5000  5.2710
550.0000  1.5000  -0.0001
600.0000  1.5000  -0.0000
650.0000  1.5000  -0.0000
700.0000  1.5000  0.0026

150.0000  2.0000  -0.0004
200.0000  2.0000  0.0013
250.0000  2.0000  0.1696
300.0000  2.0000  2.2891
350.0000  2.0000  0.0112
400.0000  2.0000  0.2564
450.0000  2.0000  13.2160
500.0000  2.0000  4.8434
550.0000  2.0000  0.2342
600.0000  2.0000  -0.0000
650.0000  2.0000  -0.0000
700.0000  2.0000  -0.0000
        };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `x=1cm`, say, in the axis options.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks. It does work for the simple problem I provided, but does not directly translate to the actual situation I am dealing with. I updated the post. Would really appreciate if you gave it another try.

Comment: You can still say `x=0.005cm` or something like this. It is a bit hard to provide you with an explicit answer since for the part that you are really after you just post a screen shot. (It may well be that I do not understand the question.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have to provide all `x`, `y` and `z` for the 3D plot, and when I try, it messes up the figure. I linked the code and data sets under the new figure. You can find code under https://www.dropbox.com/s/pg0mzjqf21xpadq/mwe_3d.tex?dl=0

Comment: I regret to tell you that I, like many other users, do not follow external links. The questions and answers are supposed to be self-contained. External links change, and are not always secure.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I updated the post. Hope it works for you now.

Comment: I am really sorry, but can't you cook down the example to be just large enough to capture what is relevant here. Other users will want to benefit from this thread. Why is it necessary to copy enormous files to discuss something which seems to be a simple problem?